# Calculating Probability of (m or more) consecutive successes

Tags: algorithm, optimization, probability

Number of independent trials is N, probability of success is p. I want to calculate

1. Probability of m consecutive successes.
2. Probability of m or more consecutive successes.

The numbers are very large, so the algorithm should be highly optimized.

N = 877646440

m = 79279,

p = 6204/6205 (or 0.999838839645447....)

I seem to have the answer on mathematical SE where I originally started this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888887/easily-calculable-minimum-probability-for-m-or-more-consecutive-outcomes/1889372#1889372

I will implement that solution and update the questions.

Edit: I have gotten the answer on the mathematical SE question and implemented the solution.

Thanks

Comment: @Igael: Could you please help to write the matrix script. Can it be written in terms of loops instead of recursion? Is the script going to be language dependent?

Comment: If your question is only tagged [probability], that's a sure sign that it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. For maths questions, go to mathematics.SE. But even there you might have problems if you expect others to write your homework.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: This is not homework Question. I started it on mathematics SE and was guided by Igael to ask it here.

Comment: In this case I'd suggest noting this fact in the question itself, especially if your original math.SE post contains additional information to your problem. And determining the formula to use is a maths question; implementing the formula once you have it is a programming one.

Comment: I'm glad to see your intermediary edit. Please ping me when you've updated this question with your attempt, so that I can decide to remove my downvote.

Comment: @kpv: Which coding language/software tool are you using to calculate the probability?

Comment: @displayName: I am not very conversant with mathematical programming, so doing old fashioned oracle pl/sql. Which can be slow, but I have good command over it, so put it together quickly and started running. It is doing ~ a million j a minute, I have ~877 million j to process in total.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I have updated the question.

Comment: @kpv thanks for the ping. Does this mean that your question has a satisfactory answer on math.SE? If it does, and this question no longer needs an answer, you should consider deleting this one.